# Setting asp.net timer interval programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am developing an asp.net website. I have an asp:Timer control to update the page for every 10 minutes. I did that setting the interval property as shown below..

```
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" Interval="100000" Enabled="True"></asp:Timer>
```

Now I have a requirement where I need the user to select the interval period on the screen and based on what the user selects, the 'Interval' value should change.

So the user has something like this on the screen:

```
 10 min   15 min 20 min
```

Clicking on any of the above time interval values, the 'Interval' value should change.

I searched online and don't seem to get any idea on how I can go forward. How can I get this done?

Comment: the problem is, your interval is set fix to "100000".
You could change it, but on every page reload, it will goes back to 100000.
I would make a dropdown menu and a redirect after selectedindexchange to "yourpage.aspx?RefreshEverySeconds=X", then you can use this command in the Page_load event:
Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", Request.Querystring["RefreshEverySeconds"]);

Comment: Thanks Solaflex ! I have an update panel and have used the Timer as an asyncpostbacktrigger.

Comment: Ok, you use AJAX ?
Then I cannot keep up, because I do not use AJAX as deep as you want to :)
C# or VB.NET ?

Comment: Well I used just the Ajax control. I dont do a lot of ajax coding as well :-). I code in C#

Comment: Ok, I edited the tags.
You could probably try following:
1. Put the controls from "10 min 20 min 30 min" into another updatepanel and make a event, when the controls are used (button, dropdown, whatever)
2. In the event in the background, you can find out, how many minutes the user want and then set it to the timer with Timer1.Interval=XY
But I don't know, if it works, you have to try it out

Comment: @Solaflex : Thanks for the idea man ! I will try it out and let you know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solutions seem to be simple using ASP.NET Ajax Timer:

1. Don't use the hard-coded value in HTML (that portion `Interval="100000"` pointed out in previous comments). Instead, put the timer initialization in `Page_Load event (!IsPostBack){ }`
2. On every `Timer.Tick` event check for the content of that drop-down (or whatever control you provide to User for changing the interval) and change the interval if necessary.

   2a. If you re-load the page, then you can persist the interval value either in the cookies, or session variable.

Comment: Good luck! As a general rule, try to separate "programming concerns", i.e.: use HTML5 for the content, CSS3 for the formatting and put C# in code behind module as much as possible.